# Max Buffer Sizes Opengl ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I know this has been discussed before but I still haven't found a decent answer relevant to 2014.
Is there a max size to Vertex Buffer Objects in OpenGL ES 2.0?
I am writing a graphics engine to run on Android.

I am using gldrawarrays() to draw bunch of lines with GL_LINE_STRIP. 
So, I am not using any index arrays so I am not capped by the max value of a short integer which comes up with Index Buffer Objects.

I would like to load in excess of 2 million X,Y,Z float values so around 24mb of data to the GPU.

Am I way out short or way far of the limits? Is there a way to query this?

Comment: I think the maximum size is however much data you can stick in VRAM. AFAIK there's no numerical upper limit defined by the library

Answer (score 1):

#### As far as the API is concerned, the size of `GLsizeiptr` is the upper-bound.

That means 4 GiB generally speaking (32-bit pointer being the most common case); of course no integrated device actually has that much GPU memory yet, that is the largest address you can deal with. Consequently, it is the largest number of bytes you can allocate with a function such as `glBufferData (...)`.

#### Consider the prototype for `glBufferData`:

```
void glBufferData (GLenum target, GLsizeiptr size, const GLvoid *data, GLenum usage);
```

#### Now let us look at the definition of `GLsizeiptr`:

#### [OpenGL ES 2.0 Specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf) - Basic GL Operation - p. 12

[image: Specification sample]

There is no operational limit defined by OpenGL or OpenGL ES. About the best you could *portably* do is call `glBufferData (...)` with a certain size and **NULL** for the `data` pointer to see if it raises a `GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error. That is *very roughly* equivalent to a "proxy texture," which is intended to check if there is enough memory to fit a texture with certain dimensions before trying to upload it. It is an extremely crude approach to the problem, but it is one that has been around in GL for ages.

Comment: Interesting thanks for the info! It is surprising that no real solid and portable way is available for doing this. This is kind of the approach I was thinking of taking. If you have a glbuffer already in place with a data store. What is the best way to re-initialize it and load new data of a different size?

Comment: @Fra: Calling `glBufferData (...)` a second time on the same buffer will "orphan" the original allocated memory and allocate new memory. That is a fancy way of saying that GL will allocate new memory for you and as soon as the old memory is no longer being used by anything (_e.g._ a draw command that has not finished yet), it will free the old memory.

Comment: Okay so need to call a delete. Just upload data again at a different size. Thanks.